Solution to nonhomogeneous heat equation via Green function
Consider the heat equation
$$ u_t = \epsilon u_{xx} \quad x\in (0,1)$$
where $\epsilon >0$ is constant. Suppose that this equation is subject to the boundary conditions
$$ u(0,t) = \alpha (t), \quad u(1,t) = 0$$
and to the initial condition
$$ u(x,0) = u^o(x)$$
Let $G(x,y,t,\tau)$ be the green function associated to the homogenous heat equation, that is,
$$ G(x,y,t,\tau) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin (2\pi x)\sin (2\pi y)e^{-\epsilon (n\pi)^2(t-\tau)}$$
I understand that if $u(x,t)$ is a solution to the previously defined heat equation, then we necessarily have
$$ u(x,t) = \int_{0}^{L}G(x,y,t,0)u^o(y)dy + \epsilon \int_{0}^{t}G_y(x,0,t,\tau)\alpha (\tau)d\tau$$
The thing I don't understand, is why the reverse is true? I mean, let $u(x,t)$ be given by the previous integral formula, why this $u(x,t)$ would necessarily solve the nonhomogeneous heat equation? If we just put $x=0$ on both sides of the integral equation, I don't even see how we get from this that $u(0,t)=\alpha (t)$, as $G_y(0,0,t,\tau) = G(0,y,t,0) = 0$ from the definition of $G$.
Am I wrong in the definition of $G$?

Oups, I just corrected it

For the Green function, check the nice answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519153/greens-function-of-1d-heat-equation?rq=1. I think that your solution $u(x,t)$ is not properly written. You can find some illuminating explanations at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Some_Green's_function_solutions_in_1D.
